# Allowing spanish special characters in input

Tags: jquery, filter, replace, special-characters

I have a search field for words in english (dictionary style). This code makes sure it only accepts terms with letters and no special chars.

```
$('#q').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g,function(str){return '';}));
});
```

Recently i also had to implement a words-in-spanish search field. I should only accept a-z A-Z and of course these as well:

**ñáéíóúü**

**ÑÁÉÍÓÚ**

That's it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flag `i` for case insensitivite regexp.. I just added your special characters to it.

```
$('#q').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zñáéíóúü ]/ig,function(str){return '';}));
});
```

Comment: Note: I also had to add ´ and ¨ to the allowed chars list. If i don't, the user will never be able to input something like á. On a spanish keyboard you first have to add the ´ ... then the a and it converts automatically to á

Comment: i noticed an issue here :s ... if the user uses the cursor keys to correct the word (lets say the user presses LEFT) the keyup() method understands as if it should check that key as well. Any workarounds?

Comment: I don't like these keyup controls, I prefer to check inputs on change. Moreover this solution denies copypasting ilegal characters into that field.

Comment: i agree. i moved the replace() code to the submit() method instead of the keyup() method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
/[^a-zñáéíóúüA-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ]/g
```

Comment: i chose @tarmaq's solution because it uses the i flag